# 2 Resultsets in Datareader

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, ado.net

Is it possible to store 2 or more resultsets in a Datareader?  I have different methods which each return a DataReader.  Can I store resultsets of them in the same DataReader?
(I use vs 2008 )

Answer (score 3):

Yes, send the query as below:

```
    string select = "select * from Categories; select * from customers";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand ( select, conn );
    conn.Open ();
    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader ();
```

You can use the two results:

```
do
{
  while ( reader.Read () )
  {
    Console.WriteLine ( "{0}\t\t{1}", reader[0], reader[1] );
  }
}while ( reader.NextResult () );
```

The inner while iterates over the individual records from a resultset; the NextResult() jumps to the next resultset.

Comment: Thanks imsasu,
i know this way but i have a question.I  will have near 40 different resultsets and some of these resultset's queries are long.If i seperate these queries with ";",it can be  difficult to debug when i come across a problem in sql query(Forexample in 23.resultset's query).Cant i do it by a different way?